# The SSIS based GUI

Tags: user-interface, ssis

I'm looking for a vendor who provides simpler , more intuitive GUI for SSIS. Our idea is to reuse SSIS run-time but in the same time providing simpler GUI for a user. So such GUI will provide SSIS compatible packages (xmls).

Is anybody aware of such tools?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

There aren't really any other GUIs for developing SSIS packages interactively. You have software from Pragmatic Works that integrates with SSIS adding template and reusability, but it's still SSIS in the core.

You can also develop SSIS packages programatically using C# - but these packages probably won't work well opened in SSIS - as they just have the control/data flow definitions and then saved to dtsx.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/12/30/samples-for-creating-ssis-packages-programmatically.aspx for SSIS Programatically, and http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/ for Pragmatic Works possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Keelio Software](http://www.keelio.com)
http://www.keelio.com/Brochures/Keelio_Software_Products_Manual.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Saw a presentation by [varigence](https://www.varigence.com/products/mist) at sqlbits that does just this. I haven't tried it myself as it is/was not compatible with third party components. looked like a nice tool though from the demo

https://www.varigence.com/products/mist

Answer (score -2):

eSSIS developping by dualcorp. You can find a trial into nuget.